# FileSytemResources in Spring Framework

Tags: spring-mvc, spring

I am trying to retrieve xml file (containing bean definition) in my Spring MVC project.
If I have the xml file under WEB-INF directory, then what path should I put into FileSystemResource in my servlet to retrieve the xml?

```
i.e. BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("xml"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `FileSystemResource`, you should use `ServletContextResource`:

```
new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "/myfile.xml");
```

Assuming, of course, that the servletContext is available to you.

If you *really* want to use `FileSystemResource`, then you need to ask the container where the directory is, and use that as a relative path, e.g.

```
String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath("/myfile.xml");
new FileSystemResource(filePath);
```

It it easier to let Spring do the work for you, though.  Say you have a bean that needs this `Resource`. You can inject the resource path as a String, and let Spring convert it to the resource, e.g.

```
public class MyBean {

   private Resource myResource;

   public void setMyResource(Resource myResource) {
      this.myResource = myResource;
   }
}
```

and in your beans file:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBean">
   <property name="myResource" value="/path/under/webapp/root/of/my/file.xml">
</bean>
```

Spring will convert the resource path into a `ServletContextResource` and pass that to your bean.

Comment: Thanks!. In my servlet I have HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, so I do "request.getRealPath()" instead of servletContext.getRealPath().